Broken code from 14.0 to 14.1
why the behavour of nlmf["ParameterTable"] has been changed from 14.0 to 14.1?
After a run of
nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[
   Transpose[{FreqEXP, ZModEXP}], {Abs[
     Z[2 \[Pi] \[Omega], Rex, Le, n, Res, Lces, Cmes]]},
   {{Rex, Re0}, {Le, Le0}, {n, n0}, {Res, Res0}, {Lces, Lces0}, {Cmes,
      Cmes0}}, {\[Omega]}, MaxIterations -> 10000, 
   Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"];

in version 14.0 using
Rex = nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]];
Le = nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1]][[1]][[3]][[2]];
n = nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1]][[1]][[4]][[2]];
Res = nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1]][[1]][[5]][[2]];
Lces = nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1]][[1]][[6]][[2]];
Cmes = nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1]][[1]][[7]][[2]];

I get the optimum values for the parameters, while in version 14.1 I have to use
Rex = nlmf[[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[2]];
Le = nlmf[[1]][[2]][[1]][[2]][[2]];
n = nlmf[[1]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[2]];
Res = nlmf[[1]][[2]][[1]][[4]][[2]];
Lces = nlmf[[1]][[2]][[1]][[5]][[2]];
Cmes = nlmf[[1]][[2]][[1]][[6]][[2]];

Thanks

I just tried it and nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]] still works in 14.1. But I recommend using nlmf["BestFitParameters"] to extract the parameter values; that's the idiomatic method.

No, sorry about that. What works for version 14.0 doesn't work for version 14.1 and vice versa.

If you can give me reproducible code, I can check if there's anything going on with your specific example. But if you run nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[{Log[3], Log[5], Log[7], Log[9], Log[11]}, Log[a x + b], {a, b}, x]; nlmf["ParameterTable"][[1, 1, 2, 2]] in 14.1 it works. I just tried it.
